# How to inquire the database after limited time?

Tags: node.js, database, cron

There is a SQL table contains Bids.

When first bids is inserted to table the downcounter starts. After some time, as instance 5 minutes I must aggregate all data and find the max price across bids.

I wonder how to trigger this event and send message to the Node service that should handle this?
Another directions when service asks each second DB and compares startDate, endDate and makes aggregate by sum.

Which is approach to choose?
What about create a cron UNIX task when bid is inserted to DB?

---

So, the bid continues according by configurated time in script. In my case it is 5 minutes. After the no one can not send own bid.

After I need to select all participant who made bids and aggregate max price across them.

Comment: I think I can use insert trigger and when first time happens I send the start and end date to the service, the service stores end data when SQL table request at the next time. Is it possible to iteract SQL with remote service callback? 

Another mind is to insert in parallel the bid into Redis(startDate, endDate, bidId). Then service can read the redis store each second and get bidId which should be requested from SQL table to sum.

Comment: How long the bid continues? And what is the flow you want to implement? What are different parts of this flow? Can you add to the question?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Where are you running bid? How do you know when will it be closed?

Comment: User creates an order and other participants can publish own bids for this order